# random number array in Verilog

Tags: arrays, random, verilog, system-verilog

I want to test all possible combinations of inputs to a verilog module. I have been able to do generate these inputs by building an array with a nested for loop. However I want to go through the array in random order. How can this be done, or is there a way to generate an array of all possible inputs that is already in random order?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You say that you "don't want to go through the array in random order" - but nested `for` loops won't be random?  Also, can you explain what you mean by "generate an array of all possible inputs that is already in random order"?

Comment: If your goal is to iterate through all possible valid combinations on an input, without doing the equivalent of 1,2,3,4,5, et c.,  but also without repeating inputs?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a [shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%2DYates_shuffle)?

Comment: @Andy, can you stick that in an answer so I can upvote? I never heard of that type of algorithm before, but I can immediately see uses for them in verification setups. I wonder does SystemVerilog do this type of thing as part of its constrained random stuff.

Comment: @Marty: SystemVerilog has a `shuffle` method for its arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to rearrange a list of test cases like shuffling a deck of cards, there's an algorithm called the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to do that. Or if you're using SystemVerilog, toolic pointed out that there's a built-in `shuffle` method for arrays.

Comment: Of course we're all presuming what neuromancer wants.  Regardless, one caveat to this solution is if there is a large number of valid stimulus ( e.g. two 32-bit integers being added in an ALU ), then the shuffle method will need to consume all that memory at the beginning of the test.  If an injective hash function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) is used instead, then you won't have a zero-time memory allocation issue.